# Dangers of Ajax

Tags: ajax

I was reading about AJAX on [IBM's website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-when/). Here is what it said,

> If the application fails to communicate, it might leave users unsure
>   about what is actually happening. If they click a Form Submit button
>   and nothing happens, they might assume the Web site is broken. If the
>   application fails to communicate that an error occurred, users
>   generally assume that their action succeeded. This assumption can lead
>   to extreme frustration if the reality is that the action did not
>   succeed, especially if a user has just spent a long time working on
>   the content of the form. If the application informs users when there
>   is an error or timeout, at least the user has an opportunity to copy
>   and paste the data and save it locally, thus avoiding one of the worst
>   possible user experiences.

Now this problem can also occur while using JavaScript or HTML. Why does the author refer AJAX as `Ajax can ruin your site`?

Comment: I didn't find the word "danger" or "dangerous" anywhere on that web page.

Comment: It says: "Ajax can ruin your site.."

Comment: The paragraph you quoted explains that adequately. If you do it wrong, HTML can ruin your site too.

Comment: the quote explains in relative detail what problems are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dangerous because when using AJAX to process form submissions, you are changing the usual user experience. When a user clicks on the submit button, you are in charge of informing them that something is actually happening (Placing a loading gif for example)

If the request fails, it's also your responsibility to inform the user that it failed, and perhaps offer a solution and information. If you don't, the user will be clueless as to what happened, they won't know if their form submission really did something, if the information they sent has been saved... etc

AJAX is "dangerous" because it completely relies on the developer to work fine.

If the network connection is lost for example, the AJAX request will fail and many developers forget to use a timer to check for this kind of thing, thus the user will be left alone wondering what actually happened. If the request did make it to the server, but the answer didn't return, the action might have been done (e.g. registering a new user), but the user won't know.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can be more sure that your local JavaScript code will get executed as you intended. However, as Ajax may be affected by network congestion and other external problems, you can not be as sure. Unless proper precautions are taken (like checking for a timeout), certain functions might not be called at all, leaving the user confused.

Answer (score 1):

Static javascript code should have the same outcome everytime it is executed (this really depends on the code, but we're talking about general/simple javascripts).
AJAX on the other hand is always subject to external factors affecting it's execution (internet connectivity problems / timeouts / server load, etc).
I have seen many AJAX scripts not handling timeouts or failed connection/reading attempts leaving the "loading bar" (if there is one) hanging